# Why does Libgdx's AssetManager use "/" instead of "\"

Tags: java, android, windows, libgdx, separator

According to libgdx's wiki on AssetManager they use "/" as their file separator.
https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Managing-your-assets

When I tried using java.io.File.separator as the separator the asset manager would throw errors at run-time. Why does libgdx use Unix's file separator when I'm working on windows?

Comment: It's intended to be multi-platform and was originally designed especially for Android. Just my speculation, but I imagine it just makes sense to accept the `/` for use on all platforms so the core part of the project doesn't need to know what system the game will be deployed to.

Comment: As @Tenfour04 mentioned Libgdx is intended to be multi-platform and therefore takes care about the file separator and other platform dependend thinks itself, so that the user does not need totake care about it.  
I guess, as the Unix file separator is used more often, while the one of windows is used for windows only it makes sence to use the unix one and replacing it with the platform specific one under the hood. Also the Windows "\" needs to be escaped in java, as it is used for special characters like "\n".

Answer (score 0):

Actually its java that uses "\".
It is a start of the escape sequence like "\b", "\n", "\f" etc.
So "\" cannot be used as file separator.
If still want to use "\" then use "\\"
**E.g.** `"C:\\libgdx\\myProject\\..and so on"`